# Values are not getting inserted into mysql database using sailsJS

Tags: mysql, api, sails.js, models

Hey guys i am trying to create API using sails.JS everything works well but i cannot see values getting insert into my database. I created my API using

```
sails generate api Message
```

so in my config/connection.js and

```
mysqlAdapter: {
    adapter: 'sails-mysql',
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: '',
    database: 'sailsApi'
  },
```

config/models.js

```
connection: 'mysqlAdapter',
migrate: 'safe'
```

here is my  api/models/Message.js

```
module.exports = {
  connection: 'mysqlAdapter',
  tableName: 'message',
  attributes: {
    email:{
        type: 'string',
        unique: true,
        columnName: 'email'
    },
    message: {
        type: 'string',
        columnName: 'message'
    }

  }
};
```

here is my api/controllers/MessageController.js

module.exports = {

};

here is the database view where i am getting null in email and message field
[image: error in table]

i am a beginner in sails just started few days back can any body help me what is the issue why i am not getting values entered into database

Comment: Could you show the controller where you have the `create` method implemented ?

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty my api/controllers/MessageController.js consist of module.exports = {
 
}; its empty

Comment: Please update the question and add the controller code into it and also `email` type should be `string`

Comment: i have updated my question can you tell me about Models/Message.js is it right?

Comment: Yes I am referring to model and your controller code is incomplete

Comment: can you correct it as i don't know what to add in MessageController.js?

Comment: wait how are inserting the data then ? for the api you must have some routes. And the route will use some controller or can directly use call back for insert purpose. Check your route what its doing and where its sending the request.

Comment: I am not using routes as i am testing it on local host and sending data through postman and data of email and message is not getting insert other fields are auto-incremented fields . Basically i am a newbie.

Comment: Ok so even if you use postman you should hit an endpoint and if you have  not implemented the logic i.e. getting the request data and insert operation it will not work. And I am surprised how insert is still happening. Check your code properly. I can't say anything unless I see the entire code base.

Answer (score 0):

Hey guys solve the question by just correcting the data type of email to string previously it was email as data-type also restarting the server make it work like charm 
I also referred the tutorial from [here](http://maangalabs.com/blog/2014/07/26/generating-rest-api-with-sails-js-part-2/) which helped me sort my issue.

thanks @abhik for helping